# What are some attacks I can perform if I break into victims lan router?

Tags: router

I am new to Linux / Kali, but I am trying to learn as much as I can.

For the past five days I have been using Google and learning on my own. I have been learning about breaking into routers and have had some success. I was able to gain access to the admin panel. What attacks or exploits can I perform at this point and how would I execute them?

Comment: You may be able to install tracking software, reroute traffic through a proxy (man-in-the-middle attack), depending upon the router's software you may be able to encrypt traffic, or change password information. All of these things depend on the router and the system it is attached to. **If it were me, however, I wouldn't mess with this kind of thing if it meant potentially harming stuff irreparably**.

Answer (score 1):

Once you have admin access to a router, you have complete access to the WAN and LAN of that network. This is one reason that enterprise networks are (should be) segregated into multiple networks separated by firewalls. In that situation, all you would have gained access to is probably the "DMZ" or outer zone network.

With such a foothold, you can open up inbound and outbound ports, install monitoring on the router itself and use the router as a platform for attacking other systems further into the network.

Any enterprise router should have monitoring already installed to help identify this kind of attack, reporting it upwards to admins and the SIEM. A common scenario is for the SIEM to aggregate logs from routers to monitor for anomalies.